# SQL Server 2005 Query SUBSTRING & PATINDEX

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, substring, patindex

i have in my database three word phrases:

for example: "JKH Drainage Units"

Does anyone knows how to get the first letter of the third word?

i need to extract the "U" of the "Units" word.

N.B. i tried to use SUBSTRING(Phrase, PATINDEX('% % %', Phrase) + 1, 1) but it didn't work for me...

Comment: Define "word". Or do you just mean the first non-space character after the second space regardless of whether or not it is part of a "word"?

Comment: the first none-space character after the second space... you said it better than me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've broken it down step-by-step, just to show the method to my madness:

```
declare @Phrase varchar(100)
set @Phrase = 'JKH Drainage Units'

/* The first space */
select charindex(' ', @Phrase, 1)

/* The second space */
select charindex(' ', @Phrase, charindex(' ', @Phrase, 1) + 1)

/* The first character after the second space */
select substring(@Phrase, charindex(' ', @Phrase, charindex(' ', @Phrase, 1) + 1)+1, 1)
```